# Adding a newline to javascript string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an "email a friend" link. Here's the script:

```js
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function mailpage()
{
mail_str = "mailto:?subject= Checkout this product I thought you might like";
mail_str += "&body= Hi there, I thought you might like this product I saw on www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk";
mail_str += " " + parent.location.href; 
location.href = mail_str;
}
</SCRIPT>
<div class="email_friend"><A HREF = "javascript:mailpage()">Email this product to a friend</A></div></p>
```

In the message body text I would like to have a new line after "Hi there," so:

> Hi there,
>
> I thought you might like this product I saw on www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk
>
> Can anyone advise please? It's on a wordpress site

Comment: What did your search for "javascript newline" come up with? Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: No I'm afraid that just adds those exact characters...

Comment: @james-hill I saw that and tried it, but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: @PeeHaa lots of reference to using \n and \r\n but they don't seem to work...

Comment: Look at the answer, not the question.

Comment: @PeterKirkwood ok when that is not a dupe have you searched for "mailto link newline"

Comment: Please search for possible duplicates either way.

Comment: @james-hill Actually the thing he says NOT to do (%0D%0A) seems to work.! I hadn't thought to try that! Thanks

Comment: @PeeHaa, yeah I did, but the answers weren't working. But trying something one of them said NOT to do did work! Sorry again.

Comment: Strange. I find numerous results....

Comment: @PeeHaa i think the problem is my complete lack of any understanding of Javascript! I think when I was trying the things, I wasn't getting it right!